# Routing not working when sending a DELETE request to an HttpDelete action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-mvc-controller

I have a ProductsController with only one View - Index.cshtml.

The following 3 action methods are inside of this controller:

```
//http://localhost:55555/products
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Index()
{
}

//http://localhost:55555/products
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Index(ProductViewModel product)
{
}

//http://localhost:55555/products/1
[HttpDelete("{id}")]
public IActionResult Index([FromRoute] int id)
{
}
```

Get works perfectly fine when I go to /products. Post works perfectly fine when I create a new product using /products. Delete does not work at all, I am getting a 404 not found for /products/9. I am using a standard AJAX request w/ type: DELETE.

I am using the default MVC conventional routing settings:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

**Here is what my AJAX Request looks like:**

```
$(".js-delete-product").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "DELETE",
        url: "products/" + $(this).data("id"),
        success: onDeleteSuccess
    });
});
```

I also tried sending a DELETE request in postman to http://localhost:55555/products/1 to make sure it wasn't my jquery ajax and still 404 not found.

**UPDATE:**
If I send a DELETE request to just http://localhost:55555/products it goes into the function, but as you would expect the id param is set to null. Any idea why this is happening? I only want it to go into the delete method if a param is passed, but when a param is passed it doesn't go in (404 not found).

Comment: Could you please try to send a DELETE request to `http://localhost:55555/products/index/1` and see if that works?

Comment: Can you post your Ajax code?

Comment: @Dobbins I updated my post with the ajax code. I have no idea why it wouldn't work. The console is throwing a 404 not found error and is telling me that the requested url is: http://localhost:555555/products/1

Comment: @rabelloo Still getting a 404 not found.

Comment: Please see the update at the bottom of my post.

Answer (score 4):

Include the route parameter for `id` on the `[HttpDelete]` attribute:

```
[HttpDelete("{id}")]
public IActionResult Index([FromRoute] int id)
{
}
```

Comment: I really thought this was going to work, but it does not.

Answer (score 3):

For me the issue was related to this:
https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2015/Apr/09/ASPNET-MVC-HttpVerbsDeletePut-Routes-not-firing

Out of the box only a few verbs are handled for extension-less URLs. The solution is to update your web.config to explicitly specify the accepted verbs.

```
 <configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
        <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." 
             verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS" 
             type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" 
             preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
      </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2):

Finally found the answer to this, but only from trial and error. I have no idea why it only works this way.

```
//http://localhost:55555/products/1

[HttpDelete("products/{id}")]
public IActionResult Index([FromRoute] int id)
{
}
```

I have no idea why I should have to specify the controller name as it should already be assumed based off of this setting:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

If someone can further explain why this is the case that would be great.

Comment: Apparently the template is not parsed the way you expected, therefore you are not able to set defaults and optional parameters within it. You must set it up like @Steve suggested. Here's MS documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx

Comment: `[HttpDelete]` doesn't take any arguments (as of the latest MVC I'm using) so this doesn't compile

Answer (score 1):

for route you can mark certain fields as optional and set the default for others

```
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "default",
   template: "{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
   defaults: new {controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional});
```

then you can just do

```
[HttpDelete]
public IActionResult Index(int id)
{
}
```

Comment: I believe that is the same thing as the configuration specified in my post. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @BlakeRivell not sure if the from route tag has any conflict with the {id} attribute. give it a shot

Answer (score 0):

```
 [HttpDelete("{Id}")]
    public IActionResult Delete(int? Id)
    {
        if (Id == null)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
        Item itemToRemove = Repo.Find(Id);
        if (itemToRemove == null)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
        Repo.Delete(itemToRemove );
        return NoContent();
    }
```

and make the call like this:
/products/5